# No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, emulation

I am Working with xamarin.forms. There is no errors at build time.when i run application emulator just stucks and doesnt show anything.at the same time it display

> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

message in output window. i have tried to clean rebuild solution still not working.

anyone else have same issue..please help.Thanks In advance

Comment: Please check the references of each project. Do they all reference a System.Xml? And different versions by any chance?

Comment: android project reference system.xml but pcl project dont

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this problem? @NeelamPrajapati

Answer (score 0):

In my Visual Studio 2015 which Xamarin version is 4.2.0.

I create Cross-platform application of Xamarin.Forms, also get following warning message

System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

You can check your Xamarin.Android project that System.Xml assembly version is 2.0.5.0 and another System.Xml is PCL and version 4.0.0.0

You can upgrade your Xamarin.Android's assembley or can ignore it.

Comment: there is no system.xml in PCL project

Comment: in adroid project there is v4.0.30319.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but what I did to solve it was to open the `.csproj` file and do a search for `System.Xml` you will find two (or more) entries there, remove the one you don't want.

In my case I had two entries, one with the version referencing the nuget package and another just like this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
```

I deleted the later and left the nuget one

Hope this helps